# Android: Exception usin iText

Tags: android, itext

I am trying to read pdf using iText. Below is the code snippet for which i am getting exception as "not found as a file or resource":

```
public void readFromPdf(){
        String content ="";
        PdfReader reader = null;
        try {
            //String fileName is the string with the path to your .pdf file, for example resources/pdfs/preface.pdf
            reader = new PdfReader("C:\\test\\demo.pdf");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        numberOfPages = numberOfPages + 1;
        for (int page = 1; page < numberOfPages; page++){
            try {
                String content1Page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, page);
                content = content + content1Page;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Could anyone please figure out whats going wrong?

Comment: is this running on an Android device? if so `"C:\\test\\demo.pdf"`  is going to always return file not found because android device has no concept of C: drive.

Comment: ok.. so how to fetch it if i put it in the raw folder?

Comment: can the PdfReader take an input stream as a parameter instead of a filepath?

Comment: It actually takes only the input stream

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - nobody gave me a really good answer & also my prof didn't find a bug.. Soo.. Now I'm using PDFBox from Apache http://pdfbox.apache.org It's quite simple to read pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

put your `demo.pdf` inside assets in your project folder and use this:

```
reader = new PdfReader(openAssets().open("demo.pdf"));
```

as long as that contstructor can accept an input stream it should work.